# Creating scenario on Jmeter using 2 hosts

Tags: authentication, jmeter, request, host, test-plan

Previously I had a test plan with one host: Login, visit several pages. E.g. dev-example.com
But now the process of login is changed - separate host is used for login now - E.g. dev-example.com (for visiting pages) and account-dev.example.com (for login)
How can I use 2 hosts in one test plan?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CL5nU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler has "Server Name or IP" field and it doesn't have to be the same for all HTTP Request samplers.

So for the one(s) responsible for the login functionality you can have `account-dev.example.com` and for remaining `dev-example.com`

[image]

Also be aware of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration elements where you can set "default" values for the hostname, protocol, port, path, whatever so if the option is blank or not set - it will be taken from the HTTP Request Defaults, this way you can control all HTTP Request samplers from one place.